# formatting only windows partition and leaving ubuntu untouched

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, 64-bit, windows-8

I am using a dual boot system with Ubuntu 13.10 and windows8. I have a 64 bit hp pavilion g6 but when I last installed my win8 I installed a 32 bit OS, and then I installed my ubuntu over my win8. Now my workload on the win8 workspace has slowly increased and the 32 bit os operation is becoming a problem, plus the hardware reserved RAM for the 32 bit OS renders most of my RAM unusable. So I want to format only my windows partition and reinstall a 64 bit OS over there. Is it possible? If yes, how do I do it??

Comment: Yes, for how? part please upload the gparted screenshot.

Comment: what do you mean by gparted screenshot? or rather what is "gparted screenshot"? How can I get it?

Comment: Boot into Ubuntu search for gparted partition editor in dash.If it was not installed on your's, then install it by running `sudo apt-get install gparted`.Open the gparted partition editor.Take a screenshot of it.Post the screenshot on your question.

Comment: The gparted screenshot is [link](http://postimg.org/image/z8fic6yj9/)

Comment: From the screenshot, did you want to format which partition?

Comment: I want to format all the 3 ntfs systems and load windows8 64 bit on it, and if possible also combine the unallocated 40GBs of space to the windows partition.

Comment: plz don't delete the /dev/sda1, because it was an system reserved partition.Format sda2,sda3 partitions and combine their spaces.Now install windows on the combined partition.

Comment: letus discuss here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company

Answer (score 1):

- Through the Gparted partition editor, first format `/dev/sda3` partition to ntfs filesystem.Before formatting, make sure that your `/dev/sda3` partition wasn't mounted.
- Now boot Windows installation disk and choose custom option on startup.
- Install Windows on the formatted ntfs partition.
- Because of the installation of Windows, grub will be overwrited by Windows boot manager.
- For this you have to run [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu).
- Now both Windows and Ubuntu options will be appear on the grub.